Create filter based on specific column
How do I filter an 2D array based on a value in a column?
I tried arr[arr[2] > 5] but it fails
>>> arr = np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))
>>> print(arr)
[[ 0  1  2]
[ 3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8]
[ 9 10 11]]
>>> print(arr[arr[2] > 5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3


since you want columns: arr[arr[:, 2] > 5]

arr[2] means: third row of the array, which is [6, 7, 8].
arr[2] > 5 gives a boolean array [True, True, True].
You're trying to index the entire arr using this boolean array, but it only has three elements, which cannot match the four rows in arr.
print(arr[arr[:,2] > 5])

Output:
[[ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

